# Can there be a collision if two threads are writing to the same serial port?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, collision

I am coding in c#. Can there be a collision if two threads are writing to the same serial port? 
If yes, how can I handle this? Also, I want to give priority to one of the threads.

For example, if two threads are writing to the serial port then I want to halt the transmission of thread 1 when I write data from thread 2 (i.e. thread 2 has priority over thread 1 when writing to the port).

---

Thanks a lot for the answers. But one of my question remains unanswered. As soon as I get the data to be written from thread 1. It should pause read/write from other thread and transmit this data, then continue with the paused function.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, the device on the other end of the cable is going to get awfully confused.  In general, use a mutex to arbitrate between threads.

Comment: Like @HansPassant says, yo 'interrupt' one thread at some arbitrary point will chop whatever protocol-unit you are using into bits.  Muxtex, maybe.  If one thread is going to have 'priority', make the other thread signal the priority thread with whatever data it wants to send - the prio. thread can then deal with it when it's done with its own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

the msdn documentation tells:

"Thread Safety
Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

so you need to make it thread safe on your own. e.g.

```
void thread1()
{
    lock(serialPort1)
    { 
         serialPort1.Write(something);
    }
}
void thread2()
{
    lock(serialPort1)
    { 
         serialPort1.Write(somethingelse);
    }
}
```

Comment: That just a boilerplate phrase, it doesn't mean anything.  The Write() method is in fact thread-safe, the driver provides the implicit lock.  Adding your own lock doesn't change anything.

Comment: What?  MDSN documentation misleading?  Shock! Horror!

Comment: @MartinJames It actually isn't misleading. The documentation doesn't guarantee it to be threadsafe, that doesn't mean it couldn't be.

Comment: @Grozz - sonds vaguely lawyerish to me :(

Comment: I agree :) But anyway MSDN is about the last thing you could possibly say was done wrong by MS.

Comment: @Grozz well, yes, that particular prize goes to Windows ME, obviously.